# Jquery Datatables issue when resizing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, datatables

I'm using Jquery datatables to display some data, but i have an issue, when resizing, it doesn't fit the parent container. I noticed that when i saved my code and reloaded the page the datatable resized correctly, but if i reloaded again, the datatable extended beyond its parent container , which is a tab panel, i don't know what is causing this issue.  I'm using AdminLTE as my admin template. 
[image]

**My code**

```
<!--  Modulo para Citas       ¡-->
                  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="custom-tabs-two-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="custom-tabs-two-messages-tab">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <table id="citas_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                      <thead>
                                      <tr>
                                        <th>Nº Cita</th>
                                        <th>Fecha Cita</th>
                                        <th>Hora Cita</th>
                                        <th>Agendada por</th>
                                        <th>Estado</th>
                                        <th>Acciones</th>
                                      </tr>
                                      </thead>
                                      <tbody>
                                        @foreach ($paciente->citas as $key=>$cita)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{ $key + 1 }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($cita->start)->format('d-m-Y') }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($cita->start)->format('h:i A') }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $cita->user->name }}</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                @switch($cita->status)
                                                    @case(0)
                                                    <span class="badge badge-warning">Pendiente</span>
                                                        @break
                                                    @case(1)
                                                    <span class="badge badge-success">Realizada</span>
                                                        @break
                                                    @case(2)
                                                        <span class="badge badge-danger">Cancelada</span>
                                                    @break
                                                    @default

                                                @endswitch

                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <button class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                                                <button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        @endforeach

                                      </tbody>
                                      <tfoot>
                                      <tr>
                                        <th>Nº Cita</th>
                                        <th>Fecha Cita</th>
                                        <th>Hora Cita</th>
                                        <th>Agendada por</th>
                                        <th>Estado</th>
                                        <th>Acciones</th>
                                      </tr>
                                      </tfoot>
                                    </table>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
<!-- DataTables -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/plugins/datatables-responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css')}}">
```

**JS**

```
<!-- DataTables -->
<script src="{{ asset('assets/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $("#citas_table").DataTable({
      "responsive": true,
      "autoWidth": false,
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a `div` with a class `table-responsive` around  the `table` tag.
Just after

```
<div class='card-body'>
```

Like this

```
<div class='card-body'>
<div class='table-responsive'> <!-- responsive class. be sure to close this tag after the table -->
<table id="citas_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
```

Comment: The datatable fits perfectly inside the container, but now there is horizontal scrolling, i can live with that tho, Thanks sir!!

Comment: add ```"scrollX": true``` to your ```datatable``` javascript options

Comment: or add ```overflow-x: scroll;```  as style attribute to the ```div``` or ```table```